# ArcGIS Pro_ Add Third party Basemaps

Tags: arcgis-desktop, basemap

Searching for basemaps with more detail in large scale than those of ESRI, I found this one mapy.cz.
Is there a way to import this map service as a basemap in ArcGIS Pro or other similar detailed maps?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the service URL endpoint, then you could consume it as a WMS service into ArcGIS Pro.

I couldn't see anywhere where it suggests they are publishing the map as a publicly available map service.

Maybe try OpenStreetMap as an alternative.